# Server Side Swift - Dispatch Queues

Tags: swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I am using swift for backend development. I have scheduled certain tasks on server as shown in below example

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.sample.dispatchQueue")
queue.asyncAfter(deadline:.now()+300.0, execute: workItem)
```

If the server process crashes before task execution, Will tasks dispatched to dispatch queue still be executed?

Comment: No, obviously not, if it crashes your program is over.

Comment: @luk2302 Is there any way to handle this case ?

Comment: ??? " .. to handle this case?" what are your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking that DispatchQueue is middleware that runs in a separate process.  DispatchQueue runs in the same process as the rest of your application and so if your server process crashes, it would crash along with it.  To work around this, you would want to either build your own queue that runs in a separate process (and probably uses a shared backend for queuing/messaging) or use a package like SwiftQ.